# SATA Driver for Acer Aspire One D257

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sata, acer-aspire-one

i have a [Acer Aspire One D257](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/netbook/2011/Acer/Aspire/AspireOneAOD257/AspireOneAOD257sp2.shtml). In this netbook the hard disk is defect so i bought a new one. Now i want to reinstall Windows 7. Im using an external [DVD Drive](http://www.samsung.com/sg/support/model/SE-S084B/RSBN) plugged into USB.

The Windows 7 DVD is staring, Win7 setup is starting and when it comes to Hard Drive options it says that no drive was detected and i should try search for drivers. It shows me this window: [Screenshot from web](http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/3518/2018.Captureww.PNG)

Now i cant find the right drivers for this netbook to continue with the installation.

The laptop has the newest BIOS - 1.15, it is reset to factory default settings except that i enabled the Boot Menu prompt with F12.

From the [Acer Support Website](http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=3659) i've downloaded the [SATA AHCI Driver](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/AHCI/AHCI_Intel_10.1.0.1008_W7x86_A.zip?acerid=634394021887519127&Step1=NETBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE%20ONE&Step3=AOD257&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_7) and the [Chipset Driver](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/Chipset/Chipset_Intel_9.1.2.1008_W7x86_A.zip?acerid=634394029047861617&Step1=NETBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE%20ONE&Step3=AOD257&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_7). I unpacked both to a USB flashdrive in seperate folders.

When i select the **SATA AHCI Driver** it does not find any drivers. When i uncheck the checkbox "Hide drivers that are not compatible with hardware on this computer" it shows one driver: Acer HWID (path_to\1.inf). When i continue with this driver i got an error message that says something like: No new devices found. Check if the driver files are on the installation disk.

When i show him the **Chipset Driver** it sees a lot more driver. When i uncheck the checkbox "Hide drivers that are not compatible with hardware on this computer" it show some drivers:

```
Intel N10 Family DMI Bridge
Intel N10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Root Port
Intel N10/ICH7 SMBUS Controller
Intel N10/ICH7 Family USB Universal Host Controller
Intel N10/ICH7 Family USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
Intel N10/ICH7 Family Interface LPC Controller
```

When i uncheck this checkbox i get a lot more drivers, and some SATA Drivers but the also do not work. I get the same error message as before.

Can someone help me find a driver that should work or am i doing anything else wrong?

Comment: Does the BIOS of the netbook detect the harddisk? If not then it is not a driver issue.

Comment: Yes, it sees the HDD. No problem here.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on this netbook and it works so hardware seems to be ok. This must be w Windows 7 or driver issue. But i still cant resolve it.

Answer (score -2):

Windows 7 doesn't support installation via USB 3.0 port. You have to install it from USB 2.0 or less

Comment: Can you clarify why this is the proper answer to this question? Please add a source which backs up what you are saying.

Comment: @CharlieRB Windows 7 doesn't have a generic USB3 driver like Windows 8, so you have to add the USB3 driver to the boot.wim or use USB2. So Claude is correct.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I didn't say the answer was wrong. I asked for context and a source to back up the short answer.

Comment: @CharlieRB: The answer **is** wrong. The laptop doesn't have USB 3 and even if it did, the problem is nothing to do with USB. It's a missing SATA driver.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Why are you addressing me? **I did not give this answer.** For the sake of improving the answer (or not), I commented to ask the person who posted the answer to clarify why it is proper and back it up with a source.

Comment: @CharlieRB: Because I was responding to your comment.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if anyone is still having this issue, but I just ran across the same problem.  Here's my simple fix in case anyone else can benefit from it.

Step 1: Enter BIOS settings and make sure the SATA drive type is set to AHCI, not IDE.

Step 2: Install Windows.

If this worked for you, you're welcome.